# Stripe.js and 3D SECURE modal design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe.js to handle payment forms and additional authnetication steps (inclunding 3D Secure).

I'm using for that the function : `stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret,data?,options?)`

I'm wondering if I can customize the dialog modal opened by Stripe to complete the 3DS flow (change colors, text etc.)

Thanks

Comment: Thtat's what I did, maybe I change the word "I'm wondering" to "I couldn't", I didn't find any params to pass them to the function

Comment: It will be great to share the code as well

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The 3DS model belongs to the issuer bank and each bank has their own implementation. The 3DS modal from Stripe test card you probably saw is only a demonstration in Test mode.